# How set protobuf param for spring kafka?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, protocol-buffers, spring-kafka

Question: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/727

please read above link, thanks!!!

When I use spring-boot and spring-kafka, and my code like the follow:

```
# application.properties
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=mock-test
spring.kafka.consumer.key- deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
# HERE: how should I set value serializer for proto message???
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.BytesDeserializer
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.BytesSerializer
```

And my Kafka producer code like the follow:

```
@Component
public class Sender {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<Object, MockEvent> kafkaTemplate;

    public void send(MockEvent events) {
        kafkaTemplate.send(Kafka.TOPIC, events);
    }
}
```

`MockEvent` is a protobuf message.

when `mvn compile` is OK, but when run it will error:

```
2018-07-06 15:52:24.334  INFO 79274 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version : 1.0.1
2018-07-06 15:52:24.334  INFO 79274 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId : c0518aa65f25317e
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class com.mock.event.MockEvent to class 
org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.BytesSerializer specified in value.serializer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mock.event.MockEvent cannot be cast to org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes
        at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.BytesSerializer.serialize(BytesSerializer.java:23)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:65)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:55)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:791)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:768)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:285)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:349)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:182)
```

Thanks a lot, because I want to send one proto message.

Comment: What are you asking? You have posted two different problems. One on github link and on here on stackoverflow. I will not answer github issues on stackoverflow, so if you want a more precise answer, then please post your full question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Your value serializer is not compatible with `MockEvent`.

You need to pass `Bytes` as message to Kafka and not `MockEvent`.

Take a look at the parameters of `serialize` method in `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.BytesSerializer`.

I think the best option is to pick a different serializer or create your own custom serializer/deserializer to handle `MockEvent`. That way you can just pass `MockEvent`to Kafka.

I have never worked with protobuf messages, nor do I know what it is. But your stacktrace is very specific about the error.